# how to set background-image to pseudo element?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

this is the html

```
<div id="tab-1">

</div>
```

her is the css

```css
#tab-1:before{
    background-image: url("http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQxJ4VT26y0vXV4ea0BVugIdFEJ3BhnZByh13xvD-LbWPocNCHHw") no-repeat;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    width: 500px;

}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6nDKP/)

How to display background-image? If I use background-color then it works but why not background-image? And even if sometimes works in jsfiddle but not in my localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must take out the `no-repeat` from the `background-image` as you are using a short hand syntax inside `background-image` property which is not valid, inorder to use short hand syntax, you need to use `background` property instead

```
#tab-1:before{
    background-image: url("http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQxJ4VT26y0vXV4ea0BVugIdFEJ3BhnZByh13xvD-LbWPocNCHHw");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nDKP/2/) (Separating `background-repeat` if you want to keep `background-image`)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nDKP/5/) (CSS Short hand syntax using `background` property)

Comment: Thanks. But in my localhost I used background: url() no-repeat; but also not working so that I test by using overflow: hidden, or clear: both; any idea?

Comment: Should I take out no-repeate from background instead of background-image too?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar if you want to use CSS short hand, you need to use `background:` and not background image

Comment: no, no, I'm using background: url(" ") no-repeat; in my localhost but also not working. any idea?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Use firebug and see is your image path correct at first place? if yes, than try clearing your cache

Comment: just check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939749/how-to-set-background-image-to-pseudo-elements-using-percent-instead-of-pixel

Answer (score 1):

Check out : http://jsfiddle.net/6nDKP/4/

Instead of :

```
 background-image: url("http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQxJ4VT26y0vXV4ea0BVugIdFEJ3BhnZByh13xvD-LbWPocNCHHw") no-repeat;
```

Use :

```
 background: url("http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQxJ4VT26y0vXV4ea0BVugIdFEJ3BhnZByh13xvD-LbWPocNCHHw") no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the `no-repeat`

```
#tab-1:before{
    background-image: url("http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQxJ4VT26y0vXV4ea0BVugIdFEJ3BhnZByh13xvD-LbWPocNCHHw");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6nDKP/1/

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working is that your are including no-repeat in background-image style.
Exclude it to `background-repeat: no-repeat;`. Then it will work fine. Here is the code:-

```
#tab-1:before{
    background-image: url("http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQxJ4VT26y0vXV4ea0BVugIdFEJ3BhnZByh13xvD-LbWPocNCHHw");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    width: 500px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change background-image with background.

```
#tab-1:before{
    background: url("http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQxJ4VT26y0vXV4ea0BVugIdFEJ3BhnZByh13xvD-LbWPocNCHHw") no-repeat;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    width: 500px;

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zyuWW/