# how to set background image to pseudo elements using percent instead of pixel?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YUj5W/)

the key css

```css
#tab-1:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQxJ4VT26y0vXV4ea0BVugIdFEJ3BhnZByh13xvD-LbWPocNCHHw") no-repeat;
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I wanted to set background-image inside gray-colored box with 100% width and 100% height right after using pseudo `:before`

**edit**

I want to do like this

[image]

but not like this

[image]

Or not like this

[image]

Comment: you want it as a background of parent element?

Comment: use position absolute and set its parent with position relative

Comment: If any idea, I can set the fixed width and height after then the :before image should contain 100%

Comment: @Cherniv I want to add new background-image

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6nDKP/9/

i've set background size to 100% - is it what you are asking for?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Now check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/YUj5W/5/

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Now with BackgroundSizeCover http://jsfiddle.net/YUj5W/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use this code

http://jsfiddle.net/YUj5W/4/

```
.tab-contents{
    background: #2b2a26;
    padding: 0px 8px;
    clear: both;
}


#tabs {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 4px 0;
    float: right;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 -4px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#tabs li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    border-radius: 19px 19px 0 0;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 47px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 145px;
}
#tab-1 {position:relative;}

#tab-1:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: calc100%;
    height:200px;
    background:  url("http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQxJ4VT26y0vXV4ea0BVugIdFEJ3BhnZByh13xvD-LbWPocNCHHw") no-repeat;

    top: 10px;
    left:0;
    background-size:cover;
    position: relative;

}
```

Comment: great! but can I wrap that image in a fixed width? but not used in before.

Comment: I want this `<div class="fixed-width">here the :before image should come</div>`

Comment: awesome! I wanted to do that.

Comment: What changes you made as to mine jsfiddle, I'm amazed how is this working?

Comment: your css was good but you was using 100% height which is not possible for the child element with position relative so i set width with 100% and height in pixel its make the element perfect block than i used background-size:cover for the image to cover the whole element

Comment: please add these     width: 100%;
    height:200px;
     background-size:cover; in #tab-1:before

Answer (score 1):

**Now you can write this css**

```
#tab-1{

position: relative;   z-index:1; 
}
#tab-1:before{
    content: "";
    background:  url("http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQxJ4VT26y0vXV4ea0BVugIdFEJ3BhnZByh13xvD-LbWPocNCHHw") no-repeat;
    top: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;z-index:-1;

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YUj5W/5/)**

## ======================

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/YUj5W/6/)** With `Background-size:cover`

Comment: Great! but how could Place that image above that paragraphs and inside the gray-colored box

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YUj5W/7/ this is what I'm liking to do but image also increasing in height this should not increase. how to do?

Comment: Yes, likely to that but image should not stretch.

Comment: Image is stretch and now check to background-size : width,auto, as like you define